# Why did attackers try to change billing address in a SIM swap attack?

Tags: mobile, smartphone, simcard

Recently, we saw a spat of sim swap attacks against some of our users in my organization. It was a unusually high number of "number transfer" requests being sent out by a mobile carrier. Engaging the users, we confirmed they didnt request these and the mobile company confirmed transfer attempts were made.

However, around the same time, we also noted a number of "billing address" details being changed for some users. These also were confirmed as requests not by users.

I understand the number transfer requests in the context of sim swapping.

Why do they do the billing address changes? What is the objective of this action in the attack?

Comment: I'm not sure this is an information security question but a more general scam question

Comment: I posted it in the infosec section as I think it pertains to sim swapping attacks. I would like to better understand the objective behind the billing address changes and if anyone has seen that in conjunction with number changes.

Comment: Most likely because by changing the billing address they are able to receive orders from the phone provider to a new address which is not yours. Thus further enabling more fraud... Although, none of us can know for certain, that is my best (educated) guess.